# Ktor deploy to Docker, can not find the specified file

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile, ktor

I have deployed ktor project to Docker. If i run the image in local host, it works fine. However, when I ran the image in remote server. It can not find the specified file which I specified in Dockerfile.

The path of my key in the reposiotory is "src/main/resources/static/key/key.json"
When FatJar is finished, the path of the key inside the /build is "build/resources/main/static/key/key.json"

Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080:8080
RUN mkdir /app
RUN cd /app
RUN mkdir /key
COPY ./build/libs/*-all.jar /app/hello-backend.jar
COPY ./build/resources/main/static/key/key.json /app/key/key.json
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/hello-backend.jar"]
```

When I ran the image in remote server, this Error would occur,

```
[+] Building 2.4s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 455B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11                                                      1.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:11@sha256:99bac5bf83633e3c7399aed725c8415e7b569b54e03e4599e580fc9  0.0s
 => CANCELED [2/6] RUN mkdir /app                                                                                  0.7s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN cd /app                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] RUN mkdir /key                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] COPY ./build/libs/*-all.jar /app/hello-backend.jar                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [6/6] COPY ./build/resources/main/static/key/key.json /app/key/key.json  0.0s
------
 > [6/6] COPY ./build/resources/main/static/key/key.json /app/key/key.json:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/build/resources/main/static/key/key.json" not found: not found
```

I hope anyone could help to find the right file path to make the image running.